# Upload multiple images to a database from a singe fileinput

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to upload multiple images at once to my database. I was able to do it with single files but i'm not able to get it going with the html5 multiple option.

This is my form:

```
<form action="includes/saveImage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="image[]" accept="image/*"> <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

and this is my saveImage.php

```
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES["image"];
if (is_array($fdata["name"]))
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i) {
                $files[] = array(
                    'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
                    'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
                    'image' =>  file_get_contents($fdata['tmp_name'][$i]),
                );
        }
} else {
$files[] = $fdata;
}

foreach ($files as $file) 
{
    if (!$album_mysqli->query("INSERT INTO '1' VALUES ('','{$file['name']}','{$file['image']}',NOW())")) 
        {
            print"error while uploading";
        }
   // print_r( $file );
}
```

If i uncomment the last print_r($file); it shows the binary data of the image file. 
Any ideas why it won't upload to my database?

The database I want to write to uses a BLOB field for the image.

**Solved my problem**

There was some problem with the SQL-statement
Adding the pictures in this way works just fine...

```
    foreach ($files as $file) 
    {
        $image = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
        $result = $album_mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO '1' VALUES ('', ?, ?, CURDATE())");
        $result->bind_param("ss", $file['name'], $image);
        if (!$result->execute()) 
        {
            echo"Problem on file {$file['name']}. <br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo("{$file['name']} was added to the database. <br/>");
        }

        $result->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my problem**

There was some problem with the SQL-statement
Adding the pictures in this way works just fine...

```
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES["image"];
if (is_array($fdata["name"]))
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i) {
            $files[] = array(
                'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
                'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
                'image' =>  file_get_contents($fdata['tmp_name'][$i]),
            );
    }
} else {
$files[] = $fdata;
}

    foreach ($files as $file) 
    {
        $image = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
        $result = $album_mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO '1' VALUES ('', ?, ?, CURDATE())");
        $result->bind_param("ss", $file['name'], $image);
        if (!$result->execute()) 
        {
            echo"Problem on file {$file['name']}. <br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo("{$file['name']} was added to the database. <br/>");
        }

        $result->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cant upload images to your database like this. You should eiter upload the image via PHP to a certain directory and insert into your database their filenames so that you can fetch them after that, or you can upload their base64 code into the database and put it in the image tag like this `<img src="base64_code_of_the_image" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($files as $file) 
{
     @move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],<destinationfile>);
     if (!$album_mysqli->query("INSERT INTO '1' VALUES    
         ('','{$file['name']}','',NOW())")) 
     {
           print"error while uploading";
      }
print_r( $file );
```

}

You can't upload the images into the database directly as you are trying. If you want to do that you need to create BLOB object for that specific field in the database table.

Comment: I'm using a BLOB field in my database table. With the single file input i was able to write the image to my database this way and also was able to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//include connection here
include'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
  $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
  {
    $name = addslashes($file_name[$i]);
    $type = addslashes($file_type[$i]);
    $size = addslashes($file_size[$i]);
    $tmp = addslashes(file_get_contents($data[$i]));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_home_pix(name, type, size, content) VALUES('".$name."','".$type."','".$size."','".$tmp."')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="image[]" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.