# Upload multiple image with krajee fileinput

Tags: php, html, file-io, input

I have a single html input with multiple value.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="fotoVisita">Foto della visita</label><span id="erroreFotoVisita"></span>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple="true" accept="image/*" id="fotoVisita" name="fotoVisita[]">
            </div>
```

To give this parameters to the server I use Ajax, and my script is something like this:

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("formAggiungiVisita"));
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "scripts/Clienti/aggiungiVisita.php",
            data : data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success : function() {
                //Something
            },
            error : function() {
                //Something
            }
        });
```

Now from PHP I'm not able to take the image and put them on my server (not MySQL).

I have the folder that I created:

```
if (!file_exists('../../Foto/'.$id_cliente.'/'.$data."_".$conn->insert_id)) {
            mkdir('../../Foto/'.$id_cliente.'/'.$data."_".$conn->insert_id, 0777, true);
        }
```

After that I tried many tutorial and example but none worked.
1) http://webtips.krajee.com/ajax-based-file-uploads-using-fileinput-plugin/
2) [Upload multiple images to a database from a singe fileinput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633226/upload-multiple-images-to-a-database-from-a-singe-fileinput)

Somebody can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_FILES['fotoVisita']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
        {
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['fotoVisita']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['fotoVisita']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['fotoVisita']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['fotoVisita']['type'][$key];  
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,'../../Foto/'.$id_cliente.'/'.$data."_".$conn->insert_id."/".time().$file_name);
        }
```

Solved using this code, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. Sorry people.